# Calibration of Hall Effect Measurement using Standard Reference Material (NIST)

Tags: experimental-physics, low-temperature-physics, hall-effect

I would like to calibrate a low-temperature Hall effect measurement using a Fe SRM.

Are there any standardized Hall measurements of SRM's available?